# FSharp.Data.SqlClient Type Provider with User Defined table types

Tags: f#, type-providers

I'm using the FSharp.Data.SqlClient type provider and keep receiving errors when accessing a stored procedure that has a Table Valued parameters.

I tried the example from the documentation verbatim

```sql
CREATE TYPE myTableType AS TABLE (myId int not null, myName nvarchar(30) null) 
GO 
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc 
   @p1 myTableType readonly 
AS 
BEGIN 
   SELECT myName from @p1 p 
END
```

Which should allow me to write the following

```
type myType = AdventureWorks2012.``User-Defined Table Types``.MyTableType
```

But it is not returning any options under `User-Defined Table Types`

This is keeping me from being able to call any stored procedures that take a Table Valued Parameter.

I'm running Microsoft SQL Server Express (64-bit) Version 12.0.2000.8 and version 1.6.2 (current latest) of the type provider

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what worked for me (probably doc was not updated yet):

```
[<Literal>]
let connectionString = @"... My connection string here..."

type TableValuedSample = SqlProgrammabilityProvider<connectionString>
type myType = TableValuedSample.dbo.``User-Defined Table Types``.myTableType
let m = [ 
    myType(myId = 2, myName = "Mike")
    myType(myId = 1, myName = "Pete") 
]
let myArray = 
    (new TableValuedSample.dbo.myProc()).AsyncExecute(m) // syntax difference
    |> Async.RunSynchronously 
    |> Array.ofSeq

let myRes = myArray.[0]
match myRes with
    | Some res -> res
    | None -> ""
```

Result:

```
>
val myArray : Option<string> [] = [|Some "Mike"; Some "Pete"|]
val myRes : Option<string> = Some "Mike"
val it : string = "Mike"
```

I'm using MSSQL 2014 and 1.6.2 provider.